# How to make alias_method in Ruby use the sub-class' custom method?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

Let's say I have a base class with three sub-classes. The base class has a method common to most sub-classes, and it has an alias:

```rb
class Beer
  def bottle_content
    '250 ml'
  end
  alias_method :to_s, :bottle_content
end

class Heineken < Beer
end

class Stella < Beer
end

class Duvel < Beer
  def bottle_content
    '330 ml'
  end
end
```

Now, if the `to_s` method is called on the diverging sub-class instance of `Duvel`, `250 ml` is returned instead of `330 ml`.

I get why; the alias is made at the level of the super class. And I know this can be fixed by re-defining the `alias_method` in the diverging class. But is there another way to do this?

Obviously, using a method for `to_s` would work:

```rb
class Beer
  def bottle_content
    '250 ml'
  end
  def to_s; bottle_content; end
end
```

But maybe there is more elegant approach?

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is the delegation behavior without having to write a new method by hand, I might suggest [`Forwardable`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html).

```
require 'forwardable'

class Beer
  extend Forwardable

  def bottle_content
    '250 ml'
  end

  def_delegator :self, :bottle_content, :to_s
end
```

It's really intended to be used for delegating methods to *other* objects, but there's nothing saying we *can't* do this, simply by passing it a `:self` as the first argument.

```
irb(main):001:0> puts Duvel.new
330 ml
=> nil
```

Comment: just be careful, extending this in Rails overrides overridden `Module.delegate` method

Answer (score 2):

This is because `alias_method` treats `self` at runtime.

**Edit**
As @Jörg commented, my solution can cause some troubles depending of your application (multithreading environment…). The `to_s` implementation like you suggested is probably the best, and not especially less elegant IMO.

One way would be to declare the alias at initialize (on the class).

```
class Beer
  def initialize
    self.class.alias_method :to_s, :bottle_content
  end

  def bottle_content
    '250 ml'
  end
end
```

This way the alias is created on the class of the instance, ie. `Duvel` in your example.

Comment: This means, however, that you can only have one subclasss, since for every single instance you create, you overwrite the method. So, if you have different subclasses, you would overwrite the method with different implementations, which means that whatever class you instantiate last, *all* objects which behave like that, regardless of which subclass they are an instance of. Now, since all your subclasses are going to end up behaving the same, you might just as well not have different subclasses at all, and if you have only one subclass, then you might just as well have no subclasses at all.

Comment: @colinux You are right, the method way might be the most elegant after all.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I will explain, you cannot, from `Beer`, create an alias to a method in a subclass, for that subclass, at the time the subclass is created.

Using the callback [Class#inherited](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited), however, we can do something close to what you want to achieve:

```
class Beer
  def bottle_content
    '250 ml'
  end

  alias_method :to_s, :bottle_content

  def self.inherited(klass)
    klass.define_method(:to_s) { bottle_content }
  end
end

class Duvel < Beer
  def bottle_content
    '330 ml'
  end
end
```

```
Beer.new.to_s
  #=> "250 ml" 
Duvel.new.to_s
  #=> "330 ml"
```

The problem is that `Beer::inherited` is called right after `class Duvel < Beer` is executed, before the method `Duvel#bottle_content` is defined. If we were to change the operative line of `Beer::inherited` to

```
klass.alias_method(:to_s, :bottle_content)
```

that would bind `Duvel#to_s` to `Beer#bottle_content`, as `Duvel#bottle_content` has not yet been defined.